# How would you parse the integer out of this XML response in Obj C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working with an API where I get a response back this this, and I want to parse the integer ID out of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<trip>328925</trip>
```

How would you parse this? I have some really fragile code I want to get rid of, and I'd appreciate some advice:

```
if ([[response substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 21)] 
    isEqualToString: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"]) {

  self.tripId = [response substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(28, response.length-35)];
}
```

I don't think I need an XML parsing library for this task!

Comment: Yes you do. Treating XML as "just a string" is a sure way to introduce bugs, because in XML there are many ways to serialize semantically equivalent documents. If the producer of the document adds a namespace reference, as schema reference or even a content-encoding, the above method will break. I'd find a good XML library, select the node with XPath/XQuery and then parse the text content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an XML parser. Using an XML parser really is the best way to parse XML.

It's not that hard to do either:

```
// Parser Delegate
@interface ParserDelegate : NSObject {
    int inTripElements;
    NSMutableString* trip;
}
@property (readonly) NSMutableString* trip;
@end

@implementation ParserDelegate

@synthesize trip;

- (id) init {
    if (![super init]) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }
    trip = [@"" mutableCopy];
    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
     attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"trip"]) {
        ++inTripElements;
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (inTripElements > 0) {
        [trip appendString:string];        
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
  didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"trip"]) {
        --inTripElements;
    }
}

@end


// Parsing
NSString* toParse = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
                          "<trip>328925</trip>";

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[toParse UTF8String]
                                 length:strlen([toParse UTF8String])];

ParserDelegate* parserDelegate = [[ParserDelegate alloc] init];
NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

[parser setDelegate:parserDelegate];
[parser parse];
[parser release];

NSLog(@"trip=%@", parserDelegate.trip);
[parserDelegate release];
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is perfect. I actually found a tutorial in the meantime that led me to write pretty much the same code: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use an XML Parser to create a proper object why not use the regular expression `<trip>\d*</trip>` to match the element? Then you can get the integer part by removing the start and end tag and parsing to ensure correct as with any string.

Here is a handy place for testing regular expressions; http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Check out 'NSScanner'. It would be perfect for this.

Answer (score -2):

You should use an XML library for this as there are many cases where the code will change
For example in this case what happens if
The `<?xml` declaration is not sent or the encoding changes from UTF-8
or somone adds a space before the trip element

In all these cases the provider of the file can say the file is correct

etc.

with the XML parsing all this has been done and your code is more robust

Also in this case the code to parse and find is quite simple.